# Separate Service for same Statefulset replica pods

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, cdk8s

I have a simple `Statefulset` with 3 replicas/pods.

[image]

[image]

the **pg-master-0** is the actual master and the rest (**pg-master-1** and **pg-master2**) are standby servers or slaves.

*Please ignore the naming i'll be working on that soon*

So I have 2 **Services**

[image]

*Question* : In the current `NodePort` service if i goto or connect to ***IP:30006*** I am connecting to **pg-master-0**. Is there a way for me to create a separate service like a **LoadBalancer** that handles my request for **ONLY** **pg-master-1** and **pg-mastr-2** actually all replicas except on the **pg-master-0**?

I'm planning to create separate service for them but the problem is they all have the same labels

[image]

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pg-master
  labels:
    app: pg-master
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    name: pg-port
  selector:
    app: pg-master
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pg-master-headless
  labels:
    app: pg-master-headless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 5431
    name: pg-port-headless
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    app: pg-master
---    
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: pg-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: pg-master-headless
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pg-master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pg-master
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pg-master
        image: mjayson/ms-rpi-pg  
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgres
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: postgres         
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: http-port
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pv-data
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: pv-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: master-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: pg-slave
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pg-slave
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pg-slave
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pg-slave
        image: mjayson/ms-rpi-pg
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgres
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: postgres     
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: http-port
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pv-data
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: pv-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: slave-pv-claim
```

Comment: I don't know if i got your point, but you can create another service poiting only to pg-master-1 and pg-master-2. You can use a different [label selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) to create the service. Is it what you want? Note: LoadBalancer only supports HTTP/HTTPS request... there is a workaround using nginx-ingress, see [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)

Comment: @KoopaKiller the both have the same

Comment: @KoopaKiller as you can see in my screenshot, at the bottom part they have the same labels

Comment: Did install the postgres using helm chart? Also, what's the purpose to separate? If is redirect only select request for other nodes, i think the best way is use a separate deployment for "slave" pods.

Comment: @KoopaKiller no they are not using helm chart. I found existing solution on this but none of they are compatible with arm devices. Yeah i'll separate it for slave.

Comment: What is the solution you've found? Are you running on Raspberry Pi? I think the best way in this case is create separate deployments for master and slave, then you can use 2 services. Could you share the yamls files in the question?

Comment: @KoopaKiller - I mean i found bitnami but it's not compatible with arm devices.
So I created my own docker image and take advantage of this headless-service for master slave part.
However, I did an experiment.. i tried to reboot my rpis when it came back on it got an error which i posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300718/error-updating-endpoint-slices-for-service-node-not-found

Comment: kind of simillar to that one..